# Add a custom View/Layout as a Seek Bar thumb

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-seekbar, seekbar-thumb

My requirement is something like this,
[image]

I want to add a circular progressbar over the seekbar thumb. It should move along with the thumb. How do I implement this by customizing the seekbar?

NOTE: I managed to implement the same by relative positioning as shown in  the code snippet below. In my implementation, the progressbar spinner is independent of the seekbar. The spinner is positioned onProgressChanged based on the distance of thumb from the left edge of screen. This seems to be working fine. However, I feel this is not the correct approach as it is error-prone. **I am looking for an approach that customizes the SeekBar**

In `SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener`,

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if (fromUser) {
       mSpinner.setX(getSpinnerPosition(progress));
       }
    }

private float getSpinnerPosition(int progress) {
    float position = mSeekBarAbsPosition              // Dist of seekbar from left edge of screen
            + getSeekThumbAbsPosition(progress)       // Dist of thumb from left edge of seekbar
            - mAdResolutionSpinner.getWidth() / 2;    // To center align the spinner

    return position;
}

private float getSeekThumbAbsPosition(int progress) {
    // Get the percentage of the seek thumb progress.
    float progressPercent = (float) progress / mSeekBarMax * 100;
    // Absolute position of thumb from the left edge of seek bar
    return (mSeekBarWidth * progressPercent / 100);
}
```

Comment: you can change seek bar style as you wanted and use android default seekbar class dont have to create your own custom one. what do you say?

Comment: How would I be able to add a progress bar spinner to the thumb by changing the style

Comment: The spinner should be below the seekbar or above it, you could just place the seekbar in relative layout with the spinner and then change the margin left/margin right params

Comment: @visionixvisionix, Please read the description. I have already implemented your suggested approach. I'm looking for a cleaner approach.